# ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object' on Angular Project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, google-chrome

So, I'm trying to get a json from my backend, but I'm failing to do so. This is my code:

averomar.services.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface Quartos {
  _id: string;
  Hotel: string;
  Quarto: string;
  Número: string;
  PreçoBaixa: string;
  PreçoAlta: string;
  Servicos: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AveromarService {
  baseURL = 'http://localhost:3055';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getRoomsAveroMar() {

    return this.http.get<Quartos[]>(this.baseURL+'/quartos/averomar')
      .pipe(
        retry(3), // retry a failed request up to 3 times
        catchError(this.handleError) // then handle the error
      );

  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  };
}
```

averomar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Quartos, AveromarService } from '../averomar.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-averomar',
  templateUrl: './averomar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./averomar.component.css']
})

@Injectable()
export class AveromarComponent implements OnInit {

  quartos: Quartos[];

  servicosarr: string[];

  constructor(private AveromarService: AveromarService) { }

  showConfig() {
    this.AveromarService.getRoomsAveroMar()
      .subscribe(
        (data: Quartos[]) => {
          this.quartos = { ...data };
          console.log(this.quartos);
        }
      );
  }

  getServicos(quarto){
    this.servicosarr = quarto.Servicos.split(",");
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.showConfig();
    console.log("Init done! ;)");
  }


}
```

and on the html

```
  <div class="column leftborder" *ngIf="quartos">
<h2>Informações sobre os nossos Quartos:</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" *ngFor="let quarto of quartos">
    <h2>{{quarto.Quarto}}</h2>
    <li *ngFor="let servico of getServicos(quarto)">{{servico}}</li>
  </div>
</div>
```

The json that the backend returns is like this:

```
[{"_id":"5ebf1383dec3c204c48457a3","Hotel":"A Ver o Mar","Quarto":"Standard","Número":"3","PreçoBaixa":"180","PreçoAlta":"270","Servicos":"Telefone,Wi-fi gratuito,Ar condicionado,Televisão LED,Canais por cabo,Mini-bar,Casa de banho privativa com telefone,Secador de cabelo,Espelho de maquilhagem,Produtos de higiene pessoal gratuitos,Fechadura eletrónica de segurança,Roupão e chinelos,Maquina de café"},{"_id":"5ebf1429ebf36e4e80a55d4a","Hotel":"A Ver o Mar","Quarto":"Suite","Número":"1","PreçoBaixa":"270","PreçoAlta":"350","Servicos":"Telefone,Wi-fi gratuito,Ar condicionado,Televisão LED,Canais por cabo,Cofre,Casa de banho privativa com telefone,Secador de cabelo,Espelho de maquilhagem,Produtos de higiene pessoal gratuitos,Fechadura eletrónica de segurança,Sala-de-estar,Roupão e chinelos,Maquina de café"}]
```

This is the error from the console:
[image: Chrome console]

And this is the json pretified:
[image: Json pretified]

I already tried many different things that I found here, but nothing solved the issue. I'm not sure if I should read it as a array to start with, but it's my first angular project, so I'm a bit confused on how this all works.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There appears to be conflicting information here.  You say it is an array, but your browser console is showing that it is an object.  Not an array

Comment: `this.quartos = { ...data };` is possibly the root of the issue.  You probably want `[...data]`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a expert on angular and this subject overall, but if I have a json array, it's not a array? Because you can see there's a "array" with the index 0 and 1, 2 objects sent. How should I fix it then?

Comment: Take a closer look at that picture of the console.  The outer most tokens are `{}`.  That's an object.  Further more, look at all the `__proto__`.  They are all objects.  None of them are arrays in that picture.  Object keys can be numbers too (though technically the numbers are turned into strings).

Comment: I understand, so what should I change to make it work? Sorry, as I said, it's my first time doing this stuff

Comment: Take a look at my second comment.  Your issue may be related to your attempt to deconstruct the array into an object, rather than into another array

Comment: I'm really not understanding where you are going, I'm sorry. Should I just change Quartos[] to just Quarto ? But what I don't understand is that the interface is just 1 object? Sorry, I'm really confused.

Comment: `{ ...variable }` <= this logic is taking whatever is inside the variable, breaking it apart, and putting it in an object, because you used `{}`.  In the case that you try to do this with an array, it will put the elements in the object with the index being the keys.  If you are trying to make a copy of the variable and put it into a new array, `[...variable]` will break up the elements from the original array, and stick them in a new array, because of the usage of `[]`.

Comment: Though, there is the question of why you are doing that in the first place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213977/discussion-between-pedroribeiro98-and-taplar).

Answer (score 0):

This code is creating a new object because you spread the response array 'data' inside the { }
this.quartos = { ...data };

You must spread an array inside [ ] like this.
this.quartos = [ ...data ];

If you want to see a compile error try this.
this.quartos = { ...data } as Quartos[];

Since this is an http service request you don't need to spread it anyway. You could do this instead.
this.quartos = data;